# Jquery Auto expand Parent div when child div height is changed

Tags: jquery, resize, parent

What is the easiest way to make the parent #container div automatically adjust height when the inner #child contenteditable div exceeds the height of the parent div.

Here's the example. http://jsfiddle.net/ULUJX/
Try to type inside the #child div until height exceeds the parent div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd track `keyup` events and watch the height of `#child`, for example:

```
var $child = $('#child');

var $container       = $('#container');
var container_height = $container.height();
$container.resizable();

$child.keyup(function() {
    var h = $child.height();
    if(h > container_height) {
        $container.height(h);
        container_height = h;
    }
});
```

Here's an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ULUJX/10/

If you want it to shrink as well then simply change the `if` and take care with the initial sizes of things.

Comment: This is not a working solution. The question was how to auto resize container when child is exceeds parent height.

Comment: I did say "in a real situation you'd do something more interesting such as resizing the outer container" but a quick update to provide a complete answer (as opposed to just some guidance) is in order, check the updated answer please.

Comment: Is the resize-event just for the window-object?

Comment: @Alxandr: From the fine manual: "The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes" (http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Thanks for the update. can you explain the purpose of the last line. container_height = h; I don't see any use for it as the value of h will automatically be calculated on the next keyup.

Comment: I'm tracking the current value of `$container.height()` in `container_height` so I need to update it. You could also just say `$container.height()` everywhere and not bother with `container_height`. Caching the height in a variable is just an easy way to avoid computing the height over and over again; same goes for storing `$('#container')` in `$container` and `$('#child')` in `$child`. Just a habit to avoid unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 0):

i was testing out this and it works good

```
(function heightFix($){
    var parentCon = $('#container'),
        child = $('#child').height();
    if(parentCon.height() < child){
       parentCon.height(child)
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        heightFix($);
    },100)
}(jQuery));
```

you can change the speed to update the height faster but if your going to use it in a editable box it would be better to use a event trigger like

```
$('#child').live('keypress', function(){
    var parentCon = $('#container'),
        child = $(this).height();
    if(parentCon.height() < child){
       parentCon.height(child)
    }
});
```

Comment: Try changing that to keyup, and removing the timeout.